# How to simplify algebraic expressions fast and correct by hand or by heart?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

if you do this integral:
$$\int_{z-1}^1\int_{z-x}^1(x+y)\;\mathrm dy\mathrm dx$$
then you need to simplify inner integral result, how to do it fast and correct?
Do you do it by heart? or some trick?
I try to calculate it not using pen and paper.

Comment: Use pen and paper. Mistakes do and will happen when doing these type of calculations, even more so if you don't write down your procedure. Correct most of the time implies taking your time.

Comment: Writing neatly helps a lot. I can't tell you how many times I've made a mistake because I misread something I wrote sloppily.